# I have to calculate this dirac integral: $I=\int_{-1}^{0}\delta(4t+1)dt$

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

How can I evaluate the following integral?

> $$ I=\int_{-1}^{0}\delta(4t+1) \, dt $$

Here is my working out so far:

\begin{align*}
I
&=\int_{-1}^{0} \delta(4t+1) \, dt \\
&=\int \delta \cdot (4t+1) \, dt \\
&=\int \delta \cdot 4\cdot \left(t+\tfrac{1}{4}\right) \, dt
\end{align*}

Noting $u=t+\frac{1}{4}$, $du = dt$, we have:

\begin{align*}
4\int \delta\cdot u\cdot du
&= 4\left[\left(\delta \cdot \frac{u^{2}}{2}\right) - \left(\delta\cdot\frac{u^{2}}{2}\right)\right] \\
&= 4\left[\left(\delta \cdot \frac{0^{2}}{2}\right) - \left(\delta\cdot\frac{-1^{2}}{2}\right)\right] \\
\end{align*}

Comment: You are treating $\delta$ like a number, but your title seem to suggest that $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta and not just a mere variable. What you did is very similar to the following jocular "argument": $$\require{cancel} \sin(x/n) = \mathrm{si}\cancel{\mathrm{n}} \cdot (x/\cancel{n}) = \mathrm{si}x = 6$$ So your computation is not valid. Check the answers below for correct solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is not hard to show that:

$$\int\delta\left(\text{a}x+\text{b}\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{\theta\left(\text{a}x+\text{b}\right)}{\text{a}}+\text{C}\tag1$$

Where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html).

So, in your case you will get:

$$\int_{-1}^0\delta\left(4x+1\right)\space\text{d}x=\frac{\theta\left(4\cdot0+1\right)}{4}-\frac{\theta\left(4\cdot(-1)+1\right)}{4}=$$
$$\frac{\theta\left(1\right)}{4}-\frac{\theta\left(-3\right)}{4}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{0}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\tag2$$

Comment: A question about formatting: Why did you use `\text{...}` on the constants?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\delta(x)dx = f(0)$$
Use the change of variables and select appropriate $f(x)$.